# Visual studio profiler not working for Azure Function

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions, profiling

Is it possible to do local memory profiling using Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 (v16.6.3)? I've tried `.NET Object Allocation Tracking`, `Memory usage` and `CPU usage` using the startup project but I keep getting no data:
[image: Screenshot of profiling options in Visual Studio Enterprise 2019]

When I switch to `Attach to a running process`, I have a lot less options but I do see data when running `CPU usage` and attaching it to the running `func.exe`:
[image]

This might be the cause: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/troubleshooting-performance-tools-issues?view=vs-2017#no-data-is-collected-by-the-profiling-tools

How can I do memory profiling on an azure function?

Comment: Did you work out how to do this? I'd also like to profile some performance of Azure Functions locally and seem to struggle to get data

Comment: I actually managed to profile my Azure Function with dotMemory from Jetbrains

Answer (score 1):

Since I switched to Rider by Jetbrains a year ago, I was able to do a memory profile via dotMemory (for my Azure Function).

You need to start `func.exe` (which, for me, was located here: `C:\Users\[username][\.AzureToolsForIntelliJ\AzureFunctionsCoreTools\v4\4.46.0\func.exe`). Arguments: `host start --pause-on-error` and working directory: the bin\debug folder of your azure function project.

I won't accept this as the answer since not everyone might be able to switch/use Rider and dotMemory.

Comment: For me, I had to set WorkingDirectory to the folder containing the csproj of the Azure Function rather than the debug or release folder.